# [[ERROR]] The installation folder chosen is not that wampserver

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, phpmyadmin

So, I was trying to install Wamp but everytime when i click on installator my wamp says: " The installation folder chosen is not that of Wampserver. Select the installation folder of Wampserver." but i try tochange the folder and nothing, and I'm lost because I tried to install x86 and don't work to, so I ask your help guys!

Obs. My notebook is a x64 version

Until here is everything ok but
[image]

Then happen this
[image]

Comment: it's because you are using wamp server addon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is because you are not downloading the Wamp server. Instead you are using WampServer PHP add on. You have to download any one of the wamp server versions.

So if you want to install Wamp x64 , then check here [download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/?source=typ_redirect) . The link will help you to download Wamp server.

Comment: The link is broken here, I tryed another installator but this time the error says that the folder is not of Wampserver but I don't change any directory

Comment: Try the download link https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/wampserver3.1.3_x64.exe/download . It will work for sure @jksilva

Comment: When you click you will be on a page to download wamp server . Download will start automatically. Please let me know if it doesn't work. @jksilva

Comment: Worked! Thanks melvin, finally the dowload started here.

Comment: @jksilva Glad to help you . Have a good day.